# Como faço um código em .cmd que verifica o tanto de caracteres que uma variável possui?

Tags: cmd, batch

Queria que meu código verificasse o tanto de caracteres em uma variável.
**Exemplo:** Se *%password%* conter menos de *6* caracteres, mostre um erro. Se conter *6* ou *mais* caracteres, continue o processo.

Aqui está meu código:

```
    :ConfigPass
    cls
    echo.
    echo  Crie uma senha para sua conta.
    echo.
    echo   1 - Cancelar
    echo.
    set /p Senha= :
    if %Senha% equ 1 (goto Cancelar)
    if %Senha% equ %Name% (Goto PasswordEquName)
    
    :Verification[PassCreation]
     **(O código vai ficar aqui)**

    :PassCreation
    ECHO Set Pass=%senha%>>Pass.cmd
    ECHO CD /D "%%Dir%%">>Pass.cmd
    ECHO "%%App%%">>Pass.cmd
    ECHO .>>Config1.Session
```

*Meu conhecimento de variáveis do batch ainda é meio limitado.*

Answer (score -2):

```
echo %Senha%> arquivotemp.tmp
for %%? in (arquivotemp.tmp) do ( set /a 
numerosdavariavel=%%~z? - 2 )
del tmpfile.tmp
echo %numerodavariavel%
```

Isto verificará a quantidade de characters no arquivotemp.tmp e setará como a variavel `%numerodavariavel%`